# UML activity diagram: fork with guard conditions on the outputs

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I have met a semantic problem with guard conditions and fork in activity diagrams. Suppose terminating action A leads to a fork, and the out put of the fork leads to action B and C (that is, this fork has 1 input and 2 outputs). If A has successfully terminated, and guard condition of B is valid while  guard condition of C is not, will the whole activity continue to action B and waits for guard condition of C to become true, or neither B nor C would be executed?

**Update: consider the following activity example**

[image]

Suppose that the first time A terminates, guard condition of C is not valid while B does not have guard. Along the merge node, A is exectued the second time. After the second termination of A, guard condition of C becomes eternally valid and it will be executed twice continuously due to the first and second termination of A. Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by **Preconditions**? If you mean **Guard Conditions** then they should be visible on your diagram.

Comment: Yes exactly. I updated the post and now the problem should be more clearly illustrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once `A` is finished it will emerge a token and the fork will duplicate that. One token goes straight to `B` which after finalization re-triggers `A` to infinity. Now, what happens to the token(s) traveling to `C`? They just queue at the guard. When the guard is opened after some time it lets pass a single token (because `C` can hold only a single one). When `C` is finished it will allow another token to enter (if meanwhile multiple tokens have reached) depending additionally on the guard. Basically `C` can be started as many times as `A` has been completed before.

N.B. Your implication in the question "guard conditions on the outputs" is wrong. A guard is always on an incoming control flow of an action. The fork will not control the guard, it's the action. And further an action can never have a guard on the output. This is controlled be the action's behavior. When it terminates it will emerge a token on **each** of its outgoing control flows (so called implicit fork).

**Answer to initial question left as common information**

Actually when you draw it, the situation is obvious:

[image]

The token emerging right from the top fork will be blocked. `B` will start since the token passed the guard. Because `C` does not start the lower fork will hang as it needs 2 tokens. So `D` is not reached. Unless the guard from `C` will somewhen be unblocked externally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated some further datails in the post and could you check if my comprehension is correct?